# MVC5, SSRS and SSIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, ssis

I have a solution that is consists of 3 projects. 
[I have attached picture here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY2Hv.png)

First project is with SSIS.
Second is SSRS
Third is MVC5.
I want to have one page in MVC project that can show the task in Data import. I want to have one page in MVC project that first list all the reports and then you can run any report by clicking on it. I am not sure how to do that. All the examples I have found showed creating asp form to do so. Can someone point me into right direction?

Comment: I have developed SSRS reports in .NET

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please attempt something and come back with a specific question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I am not sure why you gave me -1. May be you didnt read the question. as I said I DID my research. and all i find was mvc 4 solutions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used the following and it worked like a charm in MVC 5.

https://reportviewerformvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box you are not going to find a great deal of support for MVC applications using the traditional SSRS ReportViewer control. Some companies, like Telerik, have created ReportViewer controls that fully support MVC applications.

You can add support for the WebForms in an MVC application in order to support the ReportViewer control, however, you are going to be firing up both the traditional asp.net webforms and asp.net mvc processing in your app. There are also some caveats that you will have to look into such as support for partial postbacks for sorting, filtering and other interactive features the web forms viewer supports.

One other option would be to create your own viewer and request the reports via the **ReportExecution2005** api. If you render the report as HTML you can simply insert the render output into a container in your application. With the api you can perform any task the ssrs manager performs as it uses the same api, including:

- Get a list of all cataloged items including reports
- Render reports as PDF, HTML, EXCEL BYTE[], etc.

One caveat to using the api is that you will have to respond to and proxy much of the interactivity back to ssrs in the form of another report request, i.e parameter changes, sorting and paging.